# Python Placeholder Query

Tags: python, python-2.7

Well, I'm new to Python ... I recently came across this code -

```
print ' %(language)s has %(number)03d type of quotes' %{"language":"Python","number":2}
```

The result that the above code is giving me is -

```
Python has 002 type of quotes
```

Well just wanted to know that what does that 03 after the %(number) do & why the result is coming as 002 and why not 2 ? Also , I'm using Python 2.7.13 ( IDK whether it helps or not)

PS-> Any tips for a small beginner here ??

Comment: See: [String Formatting Operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `03` means "make the number three digits long prepending zeros if nececssary".

Comment: But when I write <print "%93d" % 45> ,the result given to me is 45 but with lots of space left

Comment: @Amritanshu `%93d` pads with whitespace, `%093d` pads with zeros.

Comment: @excaza So if I say <%193>, will it pad it with ones ?? If not (which I believe to happen) , then how can I pad it with one , or say any other charachter ??

Answer (score 1):

You can see detailed explain about string formatting at [Python Reference](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/formatting.html).
`%03d` means zerofill to match 3 dights.
And if you want to give zerofill in string you must put zero after `%`.